# Python nested lists join lookup reference list

Tags: python, list, nested

New to python so apologies if this is trivial.
I have a list

```
list = [3,1,0,2]
```

and a nested lookup

```
lookup = [[265,301,201],[225,302,191],[225,35,134],[28,82,158]]
```

I need to match every element in "list" with each corresponding element index in "lookup" and return the value of this element from "lookup".
The result should be:

```
result = [
[28,82,158],
[225,302,191],
[265,301,201],
[225,35,134]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
result = [lookup[i] for i in list]
```

(Note that you shouldn't call a variable `list`.  It will shadow the builtin of the same name, and will lead to unexpected beahaviour sooner or later.)

Answer (score 3):

A regular [list comp](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) and indexing:

```
lst = [3,1,0,2]

print([lookup[i] for i in lst])
[[28, 82, 158], [225, 302, 191], [265, 301, 201], [225, 35, 134]]
```

Or a functional approach using `__getitem__`:

```
lst = [3,1,0,2]


lookup = [[265,301,201],[225,302,191],[225,35,134],[28,82,158]]

print(list(map(lookup.__getitem__, lst)))

[[28, 82, 158], [225, 302, 191], [265, 301, 201], [225, 35, 134]]
```

using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
lst = [3,1,0,2]


lookup = [[265,301,201],[225,302,191],[225,35,134],[28,82,158]]
from operator import itemgetter

print(list(itemgetter(*lst)(lookup)))
 [[28, 82, 158], [225, 302, 191], [265, 301, 201], [225, 35, 134]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use map and lambda too:

```
>>> lst = [3, 1, 0, 2]
>>> lookup = [[265,301,201],[225,302,191],[225,35,134],[28,82,158]]
>>> map(lambda x:lookup[x], lst)
[[28, 82, 158], [225, 302, 191], [265, 301, 201], [225, 35, 134]]
```